# SharePoint 2007: How can I perform a series of operations within a transaction?

Tags: sharepoint, transactions, moss, wss, transactionscope

I would love to know how to perform a series of operations in a SharePoint context within a transaction.  For example, I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
context.BeginTransaction();
listItemA.Update();
listItemB.Update();
context.CommitTransaction();
```

I know this isn't possible with the OOTB APIs, but someone has got to have figured out how to accomplish this.  Is it possible to get a reference to the database connection in order to handle the transaction?  Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Although SharePoint technically uses SQL as a storage backing, we're not supposed to treat it like a database-based application. SP creates a faux-filesystem of sorts, which is what we interact with via the API. So from the developer perspective, Sharepoint is pretty much transaction-less.

Unfortunately that's pretty much all there is to it :) Even *thinking* about trying to get involved with the database directly will result in Old Testament pain. Rending of garments, wailing and gnashing of teeth ;)

Comment: Go SharePoint. Many years of relational theory and finely tuned implementations are trivialized.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use Recycle(). Keep track of the GUID in a GUID[]. If one fails open de RecycleBin
and restore/delete all by GUID

```
GUID[] guids = new GUID[];
SPWeb web;
SPListItem item;
SPList list;

try
{
    foreach item in list

    GUID current = item.Recycle()
    guids.add(current);

    item.Delete();
}
catch{
    if one fails : web.RecycleBin.Restore(guids);
}

if all succeed : web.RecycleBin.Delete(guids):
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use versioning you could try a solution that checks out your item, performs updates and checks in. If rollback is needed, just undo the checkout.

Could work maybe??

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use workflow, [mentioned here](http://prjsoft.ru/blog/?p=9). As stated in [How Windows SharePoint Services Processes Workflow Activities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442249.aspx):

> Windows SharePoint Services runs the
>   workflow until it reaches a point
>   where it cannot proceed because it is
>   waiting for some event to occur: for
>   example, a user must designate a task
>   as completed. Only at this "commit
>   point" does Windows SharePoint
>   Services commit the changes made in
>   the previous Windows SharePoint
>   Services-specific workflow activities.
>   Those changes are batched into a
>   single SQL transaction.

Comment: This is kind of misleading. It refers to the serialization (dehydration) aspects of a Workflows. The same can be said that invoking "Update" on an SPListItem is a "commit point". However, it is a singular operation that supports no transactions.

Answer (score 0):

No Sharepoint does not provide SQL server like transaction capability.

As Rutger Hemrika posted, thats a far better way of doing it than anyhing else that I have seen until now.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint does not offer transaction support out of the box. Here is a good resource on [Building a System.Transactions resource manager for SharePoint](http://www.loisandclark.eu/Pages/transactions.aspx)  Though I would save the effort and store any critical data directly into a RDB.