# How to create/delete multiple items in a transaction

Tags: sharepoint, transactions, splistitem

I am trying to delete multiple items in a SharePoint list with the constraint that either *all of the items should be deleted* or *none of the items should be deleted*.

In short, I am looking to create more of a transactional behavior in SharePoint. I have tried using the `ProcessBatchData()` function but it doesn't seem to fulfil my requirement. Is there, perhaps, another method that someone knows of to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563465/sharepoint-2007-how-can-i-perform-a-series-of-operations-within-a-transaction . @Pavel: Thanks for correcting me. Didn't think it was possible but didn't check the dates on those links.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint object model, as mentioned in the comment would work. For SharePoint csom, you would call context's executequery method once after performing delete operations.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in SharePoint. When item is deleted than its deleted. There no way to handle it like SQL transactions.